# How to set the ASN1 NumericString type to SubjectDN OID?

Tags: c++, encoding, cryptography, cryptoapi

I have a working program, which generates a CSR, from specified SubjectDN string (example: `2.5.4.3=Name Surname, 1.2.300.38.22=12345678`), using MS Crypto API. I use the function: [CertStrToName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to encode it, and everything is working fine, except one thing: all OID values is created with ASN1 type `PrintableString`.

Is there any way to make OID 1.2.300.38.22 of type `NumericString` ?

Comment: Wow, very specific question, I really hope the answer is yes, but I'm a bit afraid that it won't be. If somebody can give a possitive answer they'll get 50 bonus points no questions asked from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i've found 2 ways to fix that:
1. programmatically, using the function [CryptEncodeObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. my cryptoprovider supports some specific oid's, so i could use the CertStrToName with them, without touching the code.

Comment: OK, but if you change it in the CSR, won't that mess up the signature created by your private key? Or did you just need it outside your CSR? Oh, wait, are you encoding the name before handing it over to the CSR creation?

Comment: yes, i tried to encode it before the csr generation. actually i didn't test it properly, as found that my cryptoprovider supports custom oids, so i didn't have to change the code.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's CertStrToName()-method is not RFC 4514 compliant. Instead of treating #-encodings as the AttributeValue-encodings, it treats them as values to be encoded in OctetStrings. This means that not all Distringuished Names can be generated from the CertStrToName-method - in particular yours cannot be generated.

<s>The string representation of the distinguished name is the one from [RFC 4514: String Representation of Distinguished Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514).</s>

Here you can see that if the attribute-type is in the dotted-decimal form, you are actually supposed to encode the attribute-value as a `#` followed by a BER encoding in hexadecimal of the ASN.1 AttributeValue. I.e.:

2.5.4.3=Name Surname, 1.2.300.38.22=#12083132333435363738

You can also read in the documentation for [CertStrToName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377160) that:

> A value that starts with a number sign (#) is treated as ASCII
> hexadecimal and converted to a CERT_RDN_OCTET_STRING. Embedded white
> space is ignored. For example, 1.2.3 = # AB CD 01 is the same as
> 1.2.3=#ABCD01.

Comment: that's true, but when i've tried to make it, as per in the documentation to CertStrToName() - i've always got the: OCTET_STRING type instead of NUMERIC_STRING in my CSR, so i had to find another way to fix that. possibly it was a concrete problem with my cryptoprovider, as i didn't try to use any other.

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right. I would treat this as a bug, except that it doesn't look like Microsoft claims that CertStrToName is RFC4514-compliant.